# Find multiple strings in entire dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find multiple strings in my dataframe, using the which function. I am trying to extend the answer from [Find string in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450003/find-string-in-data-frame)

An example dataframe is:

`df1 <- data.frame(animal=c('a','b','c','two', 'five', 'c'), level=c('five','one','three',30,'horse', 'five'), length=c(10, 20, 30, 'horse', 'eight', 'c'))`

```
1      a  five     10
2      b   one     20
3      c three     30
4    two    30  horse
5   five horse  eight
6      c  five      c
```

on this dataframe when I apply the which function for one string, I get the correct output e.g.
`which(df1 =="c" , arr.ind = T);df1`
gives:

```
  row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   6   1
[3,]   6   3
```

But when I try to search for multiple strings, I get only a partially correct output e.g.
`which(df1 ==c("c", "horse", "five") , arr.ind = T)`

```
  row col
[1,]   5   2
[2,]   6   2
```

The expected output should be:

```
     row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   5   1
[3,]   6   1
[4,]   1   2
[5,]   5   2
[6,]   6   2
[7,]   4   3
[8,]   6   3
```

Hence my question:

1. why does the solution with c("c", "horse", "five") not work?
2. I have tried with

`which(df1=="c" | df1=="horse" | df1 =="five", arr.ind = T)`

that gives me the correct output, but for many strings is too lengthy,
how can I make my code succinct?

Comment: You can also do: `purrr::map(df1,function(x) which(x%in%c("c", "horse", "five") , arr.ind = T))`

Comment: @NelsonGon was just about to edit with that. You could do it with `sapply`, `which(sapply(df1, function(x) x %in% vals), arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the vector with `lapply`, do the `==`, `Reduce` it to single logical matrix with `|` and wrap with `which`

```
which(Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("c", "horse", "five"), `==`, df1)), arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   3   1
#[2,]   5   1
#[3,]   6   1
#[4,]   1   2
#[5,]   5   2
#[6,]   6   2
#[7,]   4   3
#[8,]   6   3
```

---

Or another option would be to loop through the columns of dataset with `mutate_all` and wrap with `which`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate_all(list(~ . %in% c("c", "horse", "five"))) %>%
  as.matrix %>% 
  which(., arr.ind = TRUE)
```

NOTE: Here, we don't need any regex or partial matches if the OP wanted to do a full string match.  It should be faster than doing any partial matches

---

Usually, for multiple elements `%in%` would be useful, but, it works only on a vector and not a data.frame

Answer (score 2):

Since you have multiple values you cannot directly compare them in a dataframe. One way is to use `sapply` with `grepl` by creating word boundaries and check if the pattern is present in any of the columns and then use `which` to get row and column indices.

```
vals <- c("c", "horse", "five") 

which(sapply(df1, grepl, pattern = paste0("\\b", vals, "\\b", collapse = "|")), 
      arr.ind = TRUE)

#     row col
#[1,]   3   1
#[2,]   5   1
#[3,]   6   1
#[4,]   1   2
#[5,]   5   2
#[6,]   6   2
#[7,]   4   3
#[8,]   6   3
```